# Why can't jQuery see the span?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm using Angular & jQuery, and
I have the following span:

```
<span id="datacheck">{{data.checkFiles.length}}</span>
```

The content of this span is going to be a single digit number (1, 2, 3, etc)
I'm using jQuery to check if the number is 0. If it is 0, do something.

```
<script>
if ($('#datacheck').text() == "0") {
    //do something
}
</script>
```

I can see that there is a 0 inside the span on the webpage, but it's not working. I'm fairly new to AngularJS, and I'm just not sure how to proceed. Any points in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Dont mix jQuery and Angular - Angular probably hasn't written the value to the page yet. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Angular and jQuery are not meant to be used together. You can expect frequent issues if you try to use them together. Also, they are both meant as complete libraries with very different philosophies. Anything you're trying to accomplish with 1 can be done with the other.

Comment: Thanks for the input and your time gentlemen - I guess I will search for another way.

Comment: you can check the length with angular itself - check this  - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/akPQgV

Comment: @tymeJV you were right, Angular hasn't written the value to the page yet. I called my function 1 second after page load and it works. Although I do understand this isn't best practice.

Comment: Using timeout will do but before that you will get blank value

Comment: @NickyTheWrench - If you tell us the end result you're looking for, we could probably help you accomplish it the right way, rather the universal `timeout` hack that makes all JS work

Comment: @NickyTheWrench updated codepen with working demo to achieve expected result with Jquery

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use $(window).load to get the value of scope after angular has rendered

```
 $(window).load(function() {
alert($("#test").text());
});
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/KrbbmW

Same can be achieved with angular , so avoid using Jquery with Angular

Answer (score 0):

> ### Common Pitfalls
>
> The Angular support channel (#angularjs on Freenode) sees a number of recurring pitfalls that new users of Angular fall into.
>
> ### DOM Manipulation
>
> Stop trying to use jQuery to modify the DOM in controllers. Really. That includes adding elements, removing elements, retrieving their contents, showing and hiding them. Use built-in directives, or write your own where necessary, to do your DOM manipulation. See below about duplicating functionality.
>
> If you're struggling to break the habit, consider removing jQuery from your app. Really. Angular has the $http service and powerful directives that make it almost always unnecessary. Angular's bundled [jQLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angular-s-jqlite) has a handful of the features most commonly used in writing Angular directives, especially binding to events.

--[AngularJS FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq)